# Are there any sustainable alternatives to eating food?

Tags: nutrition

My metabolism is extremely high. Preparing meals/cleaning up/doing dishes would take up my entire day if I didn't eat out/order food for most of my meals. I'm wondering if there's such a thing as "food pills" or basically some kind of shake that I could get in bulk that I could just drink whenever I'm hungry (every 2 - 3 hours). I don't care about taste at all. Ideally, the shake/pills would have all the required nutrients and I would just take a couple minutes to consume it and then get back to working. If anyone has any ideas, I would be thrilled to hear.

Comment: Have you tried protein shakes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [Soylent](https://www.soylent.com), which is designed for exactly what you describe.

But even without considerations of taste, I'm very suspicious of this approach, because it's based on some assumptions that I would question. One is that we know exactly what the human body needs and can just put it in a shake. But what if there are micronutrients in real food that we just haven't discovered yet? Or what if the nutrient in the shake simply doesn't work when distilled into pure form, without the natural packaging provided by, say, the apple it came from. We evolved to eat food, and assuming that we can eat a processed version may be misguided.

Comment: Well, I just realized I've spent the entire day researching Soylent. I think I'm going to cry (tears of joy). I'm also going to cry (sorrow) because they don't ship to Canada. This is what I'm looking for. It's not perfect, but who says you can't drink Soylent and eat real food concurrently. This is the future, albeit in its early stages. It just sickens me how they've decided to be exclusive to USA. Even more so, I researched at least five companies that ship from US to Canada and the reviews are all 0.5 stars. My hopes were high, and now my dreams are destroyed. I will obtain Soylent one day

Comment: What reason do they give for not shipping to Canada? It wouldn't shock me to learn they they put uppers in Soylent, because it would certainly make you love the product. Do you have links on this? I'm curious to learn more.

Comment: They don't give a reason, but their website says USA only, no international orders. If there's amphetamines in Soylent, the creators are going to jail for the rest of their lives. There's definitely no illegal drugs in Soylent and I gaurantee the border people just made that up. Take a look here:

Comment: http://discourse.soylent.com/t/refused-entry-to-canada/18648

Comment: @user3529796 - FYI, the Soylent web page now says they ship to Canada.

Comment: I used reship for my first Soylent order. Yeah they started shipping to Canada a while ago. I've been on Soylent for 90% of my meals basically since I first heard about it here. I highly recommend it to anyone. Unfortunately the Canadian dollar is making it a lot more expensive for the time being. 2.0 is great, but I may have to switch to the powder until the dollar gets better.